# Element 'CalendarExtender' is not a known element

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the above error despite include the AjaxControlToolkit.dll in my project and added the below in the .aspx:

```
 <%@ Register
Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"%>
```

What could I be missing here?

My page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager id="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDateFerie" autopostback="True"/>
        <asp:Button runat="Server" ID="ibtnDateFerie" 
        CausesValidation="False" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender Format="dd/MM/yyyy" ID="cbeDateFerie" runat="server" Enabled="True"
        TargetControlID="txtDateFerie" PopupButtonID="ibtnDateFerie" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that sounds silly, but sometimes just close/open VS make this go away

Comment: @Andrei:  No this does not work.

Comment: Do you have System.Web.Extensions installed?

Comment: @MariusB.: It was not installed but installing it removed the problem I was having.  However, when I click on the image, to show the calendar, the latter is not displayed in the browser. My PopupButtonID is correct.

Comment: @MariusB.:  I have added the code in the question.